# how to chang the style property in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to change a picture in my site every 5 second and I have used this code!but it does'n work!
where is the problem!

```
    <script  type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var interval = setInterval(time, 5000);
    }); // ending ')' was missing
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function time() {

        var m11 = document.getElementById("m1");
        var m22 = document.getElementById("m2");
        var m33 = document.getElementById("m3");
        var   name= mm11.style.display.toString();
        if ( name=="block") {
            m11.style.display = "none";
            m22.style.display = "block";
        }
        if(m22.style.display.toString() ="block")  {
            m22.style.display = "none";
            m11.style.display = "block";
            }

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: the line requires == 'block' operator and your are using = 'block'     
  if(m22.style.display.toString() ="block")  {

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Better way is as follows:

### HTML:

```
<div id="m1" style="display:block">Hello1</div>
<div id="m2" style="display:none">Hello2</div>
```

### JS:

```
setInterval(time, 5000);
function time() {
    $("#m1, #m2").toggle();
}
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/BMpJ4/)**

### UPDATED:

As per ***@Sarah sh*** comment, you need to show images one by one.

Here is your functionality.

### *HTML:*

```
<div class="img">Hello1</div>
<div class="img">Hello2</div>
<div class="img">Hello3</div>
<div class="img">Hello4</div>
```

### *JS:*

```
var currObj = $(".img").first();
$(currObj).show();
$(".img").not(currObj).hide();

setInterval(rotateImage, 2000);

function rotateImage() {
    var tempObj = currObj;

    if ($(tempObj).is(":last"))
        currObj = $(".img").first();
    else
        currObj = $(currObj).next();

    $(tempObj).hide();
    $(currObj).show();
}
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/BMpJ4/1/)**

Comment: you know,I want to show 3 pictures one by one!(after 5 second)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: Sorry, I haven't even saw your answer.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: I have totally updated my answer, as per **Sarah sh** comment so there is no related to your answer. Please remove your downvote

Comment: Hello DownVoters, Please check the answer properly and give downvotes. Don't do blindly without reading comments.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if(m22.style.display.toString() ="block")
```

with

```
if(m22.style.display.toString() == "block")
```

Also, you don't need the "toString()", because display is already a string.

Here is a shorter code:

```
    function time() {
        var m11 = document.getElementById("m1");
        var m22 = document.getElementById("m2");
        var m33 = document.getElementById("m3");
        if (m11.style.display == "block") {
            m11.style.display = "none";
            m22.style.display = "block";
        }
        if(m22.style.display == "block")  {
            m22.style.display = "none";
            m11.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Comment: name= mm11, should it be m11?

Comment: @sarahsh your line "var name= mm11.style.display.toString();" was wrong, it should be "var name = m11.style.display.toString();"

Comment: yeh,you are right,but I have copied your code,an the first picture doesn't chang.!!!

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add your HTML code too ? That would be easier for us to detect the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jquery It seems to me that you can simply use

```
function time() {
    $('#m1').toggle();
    $('#m2').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use. Note that it should be `==` when comparing in `If` statement

```
document.getElementById('m1').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second if block, you miss-typed the comaprsion operator.

```
if(m22.style.display.toString() ="block")
```

Should be

```
if(m22.style.display.toString() =="block")
```